# While loop multliple conditions out of range in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, while-loop, iteration

I wanna create a function that replaces a specific part of a string sentence "2.x^56+5.x-2.x^3+x^4+2" and I had a problem with the while loop, I used multiple condition in the while loop but it still working even when the condition is match,

```
    fun replacePow() {
    while (newString.contains('^')) {
        for (i in 0 until newString.lastIndex) {
            if (newString[i] == '^') {
                m = i
                while (newString[m] != '.' || newString[m] != '+' || newString[m]!= '-' ) {
                    m -= 1
                }
                if (newString[m] == '.' || newString[m] != '+' || newString[m]!= '-') {
                    previousLim = m
                }

                o = i
                while (newString[o] != '+' || newString[o]!= '-') {
                    o += 1
                }
                if (newString[o] == '+'|| newString[o]== '-') {
                    nextLim = o
                }
                newString = newString.replaceRange(m + 1, o, powred[r].toString())
                r += 1
            }
            if (i == newString.lastIndex){
                break
            }
        }
    }
    println(newString)

}
```

if there is a better way to write this code just write it in the comment, And thank you anyway

Comment: I'm not sure what the code is supposed to do. What is your goal? What is the expected result? Please read [the guides here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and update your question

Comment: The main problem I see here is that your `while` loops move indices without checking for bounds. That said, given the complexity you should consider using a regex for this. But I agree with @aSemy it's hard to read the intent here, so hard to provide an alternative without deciphering the code.

Comment: Also you're using `||` (logical OR) in your conditions checking for `!= someChar` - this means it's always true because the char cannot be multiple values at the same time. Since `newString[m]` cannot be both `+` AND `-`, the condition `not + OR not -`  is always true, so I suspect the inner while loops as written here would just crash with out of bounds exceptions